# Xcode 6: simulator list completely disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, missing-features

after upgrading to El Capitan, I reinstalled Xcode 6 and experienced a weird problem:

[image]

The 2 essential dropdown menus to edit schemes and select a simulator are completely missing.

How can I access these menus?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug. Have you been restarted your PC?

Comment: Yes, several times. Xcode 7 works perfectly.

Comment: I've no idea. Maybe reinstalling app will help. Change your xcode to 7 maybe it helps. I'm using 7 and it's good